# Составной первичный ключ в связующей таблице многие-ко-многим

Tags: sql, oracle

Знаю, что подобные вопросы уже были, но вот всё равно ошибка.

`Rno, Pno` - первичные ключи в двух других таблицах. Нужно сделать составной первичный ключ для атрибутов `Rno` и `Pno` в третьей таблице:

```
Create Table Viewing(
Rno varchar2(8) Not Null,
Pno varchar2(8) Not Null,
Date date,
Comment text,
Constraint idx_pr_key primary key (Rno, Pno));
```

Ошибка:

> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Upd. 27.03: Пробую, как советуют в комментариях, но тоже выдает ошибку:

```
Create Table Viewing(
"Rno" varchar2(8) Not Null,
"Pno" varchar2(8) Not Null,
"Date" date,
"Comment" text,
Constraint "V_R_N" primary key ("Rno","Pno"),
CONSTRAINT "V_R" FOREIGN KEY ("Rno")
      REFERENCES  "Rno" ("Renter"),
CONSTRAINT "V_P" FOREIGN KEY ("Pno")
      REFERENCES  "Pno" ("Property_for_rent"));
```

Comment: нельзя называть поле "date" и не заключать при этом это имя в двойные кавычки

Comment: И если стобцы из других таблиц стоит сделать так же внешние ключи (foreign key)

Comment: А чем вы запускаете? До ORA-00904 должны выводится номер строчки и поле, которое не понравилось.

Comment: Constraint idx_pr_key primary key (Rno, Pno),
    Foreign Key(Rno),
    Foreign Key(Pno));
Все равно ошибка. Я только изучаю, прошу прощение за нубство.

Comment: "Oracle Sql commands" - а что это за инструмент? Во внешнем ключе тоже составной  - Foreign Key (Rno, Pno) references ...

Comment: Oracle Application Express

Comment: A apex. Когда комментируете, также имя указывайте, где-то так @Mike

Comment: И продумайте какая таблица главная (с первичным ключом), а какая ведомая (с внешним ключом). Врядли все таблицы должны иметь первичный ключ с одноимёнными полями.

Comment: @0xdb, К предыдущим двум таблицам в описании было сказало, что атрибуты Rno, Pno первичные ключи в каждой таблице соответственно. А вот в этой они опять должны быть первичные. Все равно спасибо. Ещё подумаю

Comment: Подумайте. Но в одной таблице не могут два поля быть как первичными так и внешними одновременно.

Comment: @0xdb Ну в таком виде как тут, когда эти два поля именно в связке первичный ключ, очень даже могут быть

Comment: @Mike А смысл какой? Что то я не улавливаю.

Comment: @0xdb Представьте, что это связующая таблица, вроде обеспечивающей связь многие ко многим, только с парой дополнительных полей. Если я правильно понял ТС, Rno это первичный в одной таблице, а Pno в другой

Comment: @Mike Я понял наоборот, что один и тот же первичный составной во всех таблицах. "Rno, Pno - столбцы из двух других таблиц" двояко можно понять.

Comment: @0xdb,Объясняю плохо, Mike понял правильно.

Comment: Ничего, я тоже пропустил чего-то, при вдумчивом прочтении заметил. Под вопросом есть кнопка "править". Вы можете полезные коментарии переносить прямо в вопрос, а комментарии после удалять.

Comment: @0xdb, долго не брался но вот дописал еще внешние ключи для моих первичных, хотя это мне кажется излишне. Смотрел подобную таблицу с двумя первичными ключами и там есть внешние ключи + составной первичный. Возможно в таблицы этих ключй тоже нужно прописать constraint. Может что еще подскажите.

Comment: @0xdb, Забыл сказать, что с этим кодом тоже выдает ошибку, такую же. Я имею ввиду, что в таблицы, где Rno и Pno являются ключами соответственно дописать, что был создан внешний ключ в третьей таблице

Comment: @Valeriy Создайте схему [на sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4) и дайте ссылку.

Comment: "Забыл сказать, что с этим кодом тоже выдает ошибку, такую же" - вы уверены, что точно такую же?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо сделать так:

```
create table Renter (
  Rno varchar2 (8) primary key,
  Rname varchar2 (32)
);

create table Property (
  Pno varchar2 (8) primary key,
  Pname varchar (32)
);

create table Viewing (
  Rno varchar2(8) Not Null,
  Pno varchar2(8) Not Null,
  rentDate date not null,
  rentComment varchar2 (64),
  constraint pk_viewing primary key (Pno, Rno),
  constraint fk_renter foreign key (Rno) references renter (Rno),
  constraint fk_property foreign key (Pno) references property (Pno)
);
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/297d0f)

Не рекомендуется использовать резервированые слова Oracle, но если всё таки возникнет необходимость, то заключите их в двойные кавычки.

Посмотреть, какие слова зарезервированы в БД, можно так:

```
select * from  v$reserved_words where keyword in ('DATE', 'COMMENT');
```

Внешние ключи обеспечивают целостность данных в БД. Но они не обязательны, если есть полная уверенность, что приложение при изменении данных также гарантирует их целостность.

Подробнее о создании первичных и внешних ключей в [офф. доке](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_constraints.htm#ADFNS004).